# How to prevent unexpected resultset due to mssql SET statement in Zend DB adapter

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework, zend-db

I have below sample code which returns two resultset out of which one is always empty whereas if it is run separately in query browser it results only one resultset. I am using SQL-SERVER as DB.

Later I found sql query having SET statement always gives first empty resultset else it gives one resultset.

```
<?php 

$sql = "DECLARE @a nvarchar(100);
        SET @a = 1;
        SELECT TOP 1 * from employee where id = @a;
       ";

$db = Zend_Registry::get('dbAdapter'); //Object of Zend_Db_Adapter
$statement = $db->query($sql);

// Loop through each resultsets
do 
    $rows = $statement->fetchAll();
    print_r($rows);
} while ($statement->nextRowset());
?>
```

Can anyone help me on this so that I will get only one resultset irrespective I used SET statement or not?
Also I want multple resultset if I have written multiple SELECT statements.

If we cannot prevent empty resultset in case SET is used then what could be best solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Tanner can you try code mentioned above? If you try you will see two resultset one is empty and another one is output of select query.